# HTML Submit form to PHP but need to use Javascript for some parsing

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I have a form on a web page and I need to send the data to a php file. That much is okay - BUT there is a part of the form that can be added dynamically (using JavaScript) and so I need JavaScript to get this data and convert it to JSON (or any other format) and send to to the PHP file, preferably using POST.

My question is; how can I submit the form to PHP and then parse the specific area with JavaScript and then send that to the PHP form? Below is what I have:

```
<form id="dataForm" action="summary.php" method="post" onSubmit="parseData(this)">
    <div className="actorDivHTML">
        <div className="actorInfoDiv"> //can be added dynamically
            //dynamic <input className="actorInfo"> goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript (in a seperate file called "scripts.js" - declared at top of HTML page)

```
function parseData( form ) {
        var form = formID;

        //list of divs with this class name - dynamically added
        var infoDivs = form.getElementsByClassName( "actorInfoDiv" );
        var info = [];

        //loop through each div and append the raw data
        for ( i = 0; i < infoDivs.length; i++ ) {
            info.push( [ ...infoDivs[ i ].getElementsByClassName( "actorInfo" ) ] );
        }

        //extract the value of the input from the raw data
        var extractedInfo = [];
        for ( j = 0; j < info.length; j++ ) {
            var ind = [];
            for ( k = 0; k < info[ j ].length; k++ ) {
                ind.push( info[ j ][ k ].value );
            }
            extractedInfo.push( ind );
        }

        //  $.post('/summary.php',{array: JSON.stringify(extractedInfo)}); - first attepmt
        console.log( extractedInfo );

        //POST to PHP
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open( "POST", "summary.php", true );
        request.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/json" );
        request.send( JSON.stringify( extractedInfo ) );
    }
```

And the PHP file - which obviously doesn't get the JSON data as I would like

```
//gets all other form data
$str_json = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
print_r( $str_json );
//continues to get all other form data
```

Happy to clarify and post more code!

Cheers!

EDIT1 - K3lly:

So my HTML file now looks like this:

```
<form id="dataForm" onSubmit="onSub()">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
    function onSub(){
    $("#dataForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#dataForm").serializeArray();
    //POST to PHP
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "summary.php",
       data: JSON.Stringify(data),
       success: function(response){
           //Do whatever you want when form is sent.
       },
       dataType: "JSON"
    });
}); 
}
</script>
```

And PHP:

```
echo json_decode($_POST);
```

However, when the submit button is clicked the URL shows all the form data like `GET` would and the summary.php page is never loaded? The URL also doesn't show any of the dynamically added inputs.

EDIT 2 - k3lly:

```
    $("#dataForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //var serData = $("#dataForm").serialize();
    var test = $("#title").val();
        var serData = 'test1='+test;
    //POST to PHP
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "summary.php",
       data: serData,
       success: function(response){
           //Do whatever you want when form is sent.
       },
       dataType: "JSON"
    });
```

In the PHP file:

```
$test = $_POST["test1"];
echo $test;
```

There is no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the onSubmit function from your form tag, also get rid of the function onSub(){ because the jQuery event handler does it all for you. `$("#dataSub")...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery as far I can see in your code, the solution to do this is a lot simpler.

Your JavaScript code will be as simple as:

```
$("#dataForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $("#dataForm").serializeArray();
        //POST to PHP
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "summary.php",
           data: JSON.Stringify(data),
           success: function(response){
               //Do whatever you want when form is sent.
           },
           dataType: "JSON"
        });
});
```

After this, just make sure to read your POST data correctly with `json_decode()` in PHP. Try some debbuging first to see what you are getting server-side by echoing the entire POST result.

Comment: Hi k3lly - I am not actually getting any data server-side. I've tried to use a test variable and I can't even retrieve that. I have updated my question.

Comment: You were using `json_decode()` on a $_POST variable, which won't format your data to JSON because it's not JSON syntax. You got two options. Return from PHP: `json_encode($_POST)` or remove the DataType from your javascript AJAX request.

Comment: Okay I've removed the DataType from the AJAX request, I'm no longer using `json_decode()`. I am still having the same issue in that, all the data is visible in the url, which is not what POST is meant to do (eg. `http://localhost:8080/?title=Testing`), and no data is passed to the PHP script. This PHP script is meant to open display some HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing the data via your JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest`, then you don't need the form to be submitted - add an event listener and use `preventDefault` through JavaScript, and use `document.getElementById` to get the form:

```
<form id="dataForm">
    <!-- Your form data here
</form>
```

JS:

```
function parseData() {
    var form = formID;

    //list of divs with this class name - dynamically added
    var infoDivs = form.getElementsByClassName( "actorInfoDiv" );
    var info = [];

    //loop through each div and append the raw data
    for ( i = 0; i < infoDivs.length; i++ ) {
        info.push( [ ...infoDivs[ i ].getElementsByClassName( "actorInfo" ) ] );
    }

    //extract the value of the input from the raw data
    var extractedInfo = [];
    for ( j = 0; j < info.length; j++ ) {
        var ind = [];
        for ( k = 0; k < info[ j ].length; k++ ) {
            ind.push( info[ j ][ k ].value );
        }
        extractedInfo.push( ind );
    }

    //  $.post('/summary.php',{array: JSON.stringify(extractedInfo)}); - first attepmt
    console.log( extractedInfo );

    //POST to PHP
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( "POST", "summary.php", true );
    request.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/json" );
    request.send( JSON.stringify( extractedInfo ) );
}

document.getElementById("dataForm").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    parseData();
});
```